# How to make project addable to other projects gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I don't know if Im understanding it right, but how do i make a project become addable on android gradle's dependency, more like facebook's sdk where we add compile 'com.facebook.....'. I'm new to this topic so please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: IMHO you need to [create a library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html). Then, you need to [publish it](https://medium.com/@daniellevass/how-to-publish-your-android-studio-library-to-jcenter-5384172c4739#.spjdbhfqo)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add another gradle project in your current one. (assuming it is inside the current projects root directory)

in `settings.gradle` file add

```
include ':name-of-the-dir-of-the-project-you-want-to-include'
```

in `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':name-of-the-project-you-want-to-include')
}
```

Comment: I'd like my project to be able to be imported everywhere via gradle.

Comment: then you will have to publish the library.
1. Local access: publish to a locally running maven repo
2. Private access: set up an [artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) 
3. Public access: publish to maven or jCenter